# Firebase Firestore Rules get() Not Working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Most of my Firestore rules are working. Finding If A User is Signed and has a document under Clearance. The only thing is, I want to find out what that clearance is. To do so I the function

```
function UserClearance() {
    return Number(
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Clearance/$(request.auth.uid)).a || 
        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Clearance/$(request.auth.uid)).data.a
    );
}
```

That I then compare to a number like so

allow write: `if UserClearance() > 1;`

Though I have has no success with this function and was wondering how I get it to work.

[Clearance Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGayJ.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the collection and document structure you're working with.

Comment: Also, when you use get(), you don't use `/databases/$(database)/documents`.  Just the path of the document starting with the collection.

Comment: Yes you are....

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It works for me:

```
// helper functions
function clearance(database) {
   return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Clearance/$(request.auth.uid)).data.a > 1
}

// security rules
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Clearance {
     allow read: if clearance(database);
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure that you use the variable `database` in the right scope.

Resource: [Firebase guides: access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: This is it!! "Make sure that you use the variable database in the right scope." Thank you for saving my 2 hours of frustration!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had an array in the database with {data: {a: 1}} instead of {a: 1}. So when you call get().data, don't use it in the database the keyword data. Just a.